# NetBeans Android Installation error

Tags: android, netbeans

first time NBandroid user here, I've followed the instructions of 1 video and 3 textual tutorials on installing it into NetBeans, I can create a Android project, **The code itself doesn't give errors** but when I try run it it gives an innumerably large amount of errors, 
[Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU9Tv.png)

I have 32bit netbeans version 8.2, java 32bit version 8u111 and windows 8 
64bit.

I did as they said to the best of my knowledge, downloaded SDK and all the extra packages i needed (but only android 4.4.2 API not earlier or later), loaded it under tools->options, set nb android in the update list etc, Any help appreciated, sorry if I left out any info, I really need this problem sorted out soon.

Comment: What errors? They would probably help.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use Netbeans for developing Android apps.

Android Studio is the official IDE and NetBeans and Eclipse both are not supported by Google (the developer of Android).

Just try [image: Android Studio]

Comment: Can't afford the data right now, and this isn't for the app store, just a small app for this local organisation. Thanks though,

Comment: Do yourself the favour - Use Android Studio. Even for a minor app it will be much easier. The fact that you can't even compile the project alone should be enough reason to use Android Studio where you'll never have such a problem. If you can't afford the data, ask a friend. You can't tell me you can't download something in 2016 because data's too expensive.

Comment: There are a million reasons why Felix's suggestion is the only rational plan of action for you....

Comment: I'm using landlords internet, I cant download something bigger than a gb, if i had the option i would totally use android studio, but that not an option right now.

Comment: But you know that Android Studio is only 423mb?

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-24' in: C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)


this is in download studio, i used quickfix to download what it  said, and it said it was successful, but  gives exactly the same error

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. It looks like NBAndroid does not work with Netbeans 8.2.

It worked for me with Netbeans 8.1.